Can i push to a forked repository without creating a pull request notification?
I have a remote repository that I've been making contributions to. The way I did this was by creating a fork of this repository on my git and periodically pushing my local developments to a branch on this forked remote. Once I finished my contributions I made a pull request to the original repository and had my changes pushed there.
Now I would like to continue to use my remote repository for personal development, however, when I pushed to my forked remote on a new branch there is a notification on the original upstream repository saying that I've done this push. Is there a way for me to use this repository without this happening everytime + some way to revert this notification?
I tried to push to my remote repository, forked from an upstream. The push was successful but everyone on the upstream repo was notified of my push. I was expecting it to only be visible to me since I created a new branch to push to.

Something can be a fork without github knowing it's a fork. Have you considered creating a separate repo and just pushing the cloned repo to it?

What does "creating a fork of this repository on my git" mean? Do you mean in your own GitHub account? (Git and GitHub are two very different things, so the distinction matters.) What does "my remote repository forked from an upstream" mean? What does "there is a notification" means? I'm asking because this is a very common scenario — I very often fork a public repo and work on my fork, and no one gets a "notification" when I push to my repo. So there is something odd or indeterminate happening here; we need details about your setup.
